# 'this.name' in a Javascript ES6 class, can it be just 'name'?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I've got this class which is working well, but I was just curious if it was possible to change it so that in my template, I could type `name` instead of `this.name`. With ES5 class style, I think you can do something like `this.template = function(content, i) {}` but I haven't gotten `this.template(content, i) {}` to work. Is this even possible to do or am I stuck writing `this.name` everytime I want to return the name key from my json?

```
person = class {
  constructor(data) { Object.assign(this, data); }
  template(content, i) {
    content.push(`
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          ${key('<h4 class="card-title">', this.name, '</h4>')}
          ${key('<h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">', this.title, '</h6>')}
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          ${each('<li class="list-group-item">', this.school.reverse(), '</li>')}
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block">
          <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">Bio</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    `);
  }
};
```

Comment: You could wrap the contents of the method inside a `with(this){ ... }` statement... if class syntax didn't force strict mode, where `with` is forbidden.

Comment: I like the sound of that. Makes me want to convert my class to ES5.

Comment: Then be aware `with` has important performance costs, and is considered bad practice. But yes, would work.

Comment: Oh, well in that case, it makes no sense to do it. Still, you did answer the question. I've never actually used `with`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
  template(content, i) {
    const {name, title, ...} = this;
    content.push(`
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          ${key('<h4 class="card-title">', name, '</h4>')}
          ...
```

Stick to custom templating system if this is not brief enough.

As for `this.template`, the comparison is not correct. `template(content, i) { ... }` is the syntax for class methods, it is a shortcut for `Class.prototype.template = function template(content, i) { ... }`;

Comment: I see this answers my question. In my use-case, I'm trying to keep it so I don't have to actually log the key names in a variable. I tried following your method with generated key names but I'm having trouble. I'm not sure why this doesn't work. `var {Object.keys(this).toString()} = this;` I've tried building the object a dozen different ways but in the end, it seems like it may have to be input manually to avoid `this`. The only reason I'm even trying to do it is so that if I've got a user writing a template, they won't have to worry about writing anything other than key names.

Comment: [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) doesn't work like that, you probably need to read more on this. This `const {name, title, ...} = this` allows IDE to perform static analysis and alert the developer if some of those properties don't exist. This is what JS can propose. I would recommend against using `with`, because it has deprecated status (for very good reasons).

Comment: To make the templates editable for non-developers use third-party templates (Handlebars, Swig, etc) that are able to do some foolproof job and get the keys from provided context (e.g. `this`) automagically.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why I was trying to do templates on my own. It really does make more sense to just use a proven engine like that. Thanks for your investment into this situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use desctructing Es6

person = class {
  constructor(data) { Object.assign(this, data); }
  template(content, i) {
    let {name} = this;
    content.push(`
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          ${key('<h4 class="card-title">', name, '</h4>')}
          ${key('<h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">', this.title, '</h6>')}
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          ${each('<li class="list-group-item">', this.school.reverse(), '</li>')}
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block">
          <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">Bio</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    `);
  }
};
```